# Smallest number of primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $P$ be a set of primes, such that for each nonnegative integer $n$, $19⋅8^n+17$ is divisible by some prime $p$ in $P$. Find the smallest possible number of elements in $P$. How do I start the problem? Thanks.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: I've read the other question several times, and I don't think that it's a duplicate of this question. In fact, except for the expression at hand - $19\cdot8^n+17$ - which is indeed identical, I don't quite see the "duplicate-ness". This question asks to find the smallest set of primes that can divide the expression for any natural value of $n$. The other question asks to prove that the expression is not prime for any natural value of $n$. So except for the expression itself, along with the relation to prime numbers, I think that it can hardly be considered duplicate.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: Continuing the previous (long) comment, can you please reconsider this? P.S., I admit that I might be "un-objective" here due to my answer below, but I honestly think that the two questions are not the same. Thanks.

Comment: @barak The covering congruences arguments easily yield the result. But I'll undo my vote per your request.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1153492/242) to a very closely related question for the standard technique of covering congruences (see esp. the paper of Schinzel linked there).

Comment: @BillDubuque: Thanks (for both).

Answer (score 6):

The smallest possible number of elements in $P$ is $3$, with $P=\{3,5,13\}$:

- $n\equiv0\pmod4\implies 3|19\cdot8^n+17$
- $n\equiv1\pmod4\implies13|19\cdot8^n+17$
- $n\equiv2\pmod4\implies 3|19\cdot8^n+17$
- $n\equiv3\pmod4\implies 5|19\cdot8^n+17$

Let's prove each one of these statements by induction.

---

**First, show that this is true for $n=0$:**

- $\small{19\cdot8^{0}+17= 3\cdot  12}$
- $\small{19\cdot8^{1}+17=13\cdot  13}$
- $\small{19\cdot8^{2}+17= 3\cdot 411}$
- $\small{19\cdot8^{3}+17= 5\cdot1949}$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

- $\small{19\cdot8^{4n+0}+17= 3a}$
- $\small{19\cdot8^{4n+1}+17=13b}$
- $\small{19\cdot8^{4n+2}+17= 3c}$
- $\small{19\cdot8^{4n+3}+17= 5d}$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

- $\small{19\cdot8^{4n+4}+17=4096\cdot(\color{red}{19\cdot8^{4n+0}+17})-69615=4096\cdot\color{red}{ 3a}-69615= 3\cdot(4096a-23205)}$
- $\small{19\cdot8^{4n+5}+17=4096\cdot(\color{red}{19\cdot8^{4n+1}+17})-69615=4096\cdot\color{red}{13b}-69615=13\cdot(4096b- 5355)}$
- $\small{19\cdot8^{4n+6}+17=4096\cdot(\color{red}{19\cdot8^{4n+2}+17})-69615=4096\cdot\color{red}{ 3c}-69615= 3\cdot(4096c-23205)}$
- $\small{19\cdot8^{4n+7}+17=4096\cdot(\color{red}{19\cdot8^{4n+3}+17})-69615=4096\cdot\color{red}{ 5d}-69615= 5\cdot(4096d-13923)}$

---

The smallest possible number of elements in $P$ is $3$ because:

- The base-cases show that there must be at least $3$ elements in $P$
- The induction-steps show that the elements $3,5,13$ are sufficient

Comment: (+1) You just need to add that $A_1,A_2,A_3$, where $A_n=19\cdot 8^n+17$, are mutually coprime to prove that $3$ is really the minimum.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Thank you. I have now completed the proof.