# On a problem of Schinzel about reducibility of polynomials!

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let
$
f(x)=5x^9+6x^8+3x^6+8x^5+9x^3+6x^2+8x+3
$.
Prove that
$x^nf(x)+12$
is reducible in
$\mathbb Z[x]$
for any positive integer $n$.

---

This problem is due to polish mathematician [Andrzej Schinzel](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrzej_Schinzel).

Comment: see [this paper](http://people.math.sc.edu/filaseta/papers/ActaSubmission022012.pdf).

Comment: This is a typical application of covering congruences as in [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1153568/242)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\omega=e^{\frac{\pi i}{6}}$ be a primitive twelfth root of unity. Since:
$$ f(\omega) = f(i) = 12i,\qquad f(-1)=-12,\qquad f(\omega^2)=12\omega^4$$
for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have that $x^n f(x)+12$ is divided by some polynomial among:
$$ (x+1),\quad(x^2+1),\quad(x^2+x+1),\quad(x^2-x+1),\quad(x^4-x^2+1).$$

Comment: What do the roots of unity have anything to do with? This was done by modular arithmetics in the paper.

Comment: @mathreadler: just to be clear, to compute $p(i)$ is more or less the same as computing $p(x)\pmod{(x^2+1)}$.

Comment: Ah of course. Thanks for the clarification.